# How to restart Transactions and Block stream in Hive Blockchain

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I'm using [Hive-Blockchain](https://www.hiveblockchain.com/) SDK for NodeJS, [hive-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hiveio/hive-js)
I can successfully connect to the Blockchain, retrieves blocks and transactions via [getBlockStream](https://developers.hive.io/tutorials-javascript/stream_blockchain_transactions.html) API, but I reach the end of the stream event, I do not find a standard way to restart the stream:

```
client.blockchain.getBlockStream({ mode: dhive.BlockchainMode.Latest })
                    .on('data', handleBlock)
                    .on('error', errorBlock)
                    .on('end', () => {
                        console.log('Reached end of stream')
                        // restart stream here?
                    
                    });
```

In fact, it is possibile to pause the stream and resume:

```
//pause stream
pauseStream = async () => {
    state = stream.pause();
};

//resume stream
resumeStream = async () => {
    state = state.resume();
};
```

but apparently not to `restart`.